# passing multiple parameters using Ajax(url) in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, parameters

Am having trouble getting multiple parameters with Ajax in MVC. I have two fields that require an input. Input field for Username and CommentText.

I am defining these parameters in the url section of the ajax. It is working fine when I only pass one parameter(works for both when tried separately), but as soon as I try both the latter parameter does not work.

**Ajax function:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
            url: "Home/AddComment?CommentText=" + $("#CommentText").val() + "&Username=" + $("Username").val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Comment) {
                //some function
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                //some code
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Should I maybe be passing the parameters through "data" instead?

**Edit:**
**This is the controller that should catch these parameters.**

```
 public JsonResult AddComment(string commentText, string username)
        {
            Comment c = new Comment() { CommentText = commentText, Username = username };
            CommentRepository.Instance.AddComment(c);
            return Json(GetComments(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: You should pass them not via url but as a data

Comment: Also, you will get an error here `$("Username").val()` don't forget to add `#` like `$("#Username").val()`

Comment: well the missing # was the error.. Why is it more preferable to pass it as data vs passing through the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Home/AddComment',
    data: { CommentText: $("#CommentText").val(), 
             Username: $("#Username").val() },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {            
        desc = result;
    }
});
```

And then in your **controller**:

```
public string AddComment(string CommentText, string Username)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: check the update.. I have a controller that takes in these parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
     $("#button").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
             url: "Home/AddComment",
              data: '{"CommentText":"' + $("#CommentText").val() + '", "Username":"' + $("Username").val() + '"}'
            dataType: "json",
             success: function (Comment) {
                 //some function
             },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                 //some code
           }
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can move you all variables/parameters into one array, and then you can try the following..
and then you can read these array values in C#....

```
var val1=$("#componentName1").val();
var val2=$("#componentName2").val();
...
var parameterArray={val1,val2,val3....}
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
         url: "Home/AddComment",
          data: parameterArray,
        dataType: "json",
         success: function (Comment) {
             //some function
         },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
             //some code
       }
    });
```